# Android - Face Detection library not loading

Tags: android, api, detection, face-detection, face-recognition

I am trying to implement face detection in my Android app, so I tried the sample app provided by the official documentation here: [Google's Face Detection Sample App](https://developers.google.com/vision/getting-started#download_and_run_the_sample_app)
I do manage to get the app running and the image is displayed, but the small circles corresponding to the landmarks do not appear. There actually is a note in the tutorial I mentioned above about the library being downloaded upon installation of the app, which means face detection might not be available right away.

```
 if (!safeDetector.isOperational()) {
        // Note: The first time that an app using face API is installed on a device, GMS will
        // download a native library to the device in order to do detection.  Usually this
        // completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that download has not yet
        // completed, then the above call will not detect any faces.
        //
        // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native library is currently
        // available.  The detector will automatically become operational once the library
        // download completes on device.
        Log.w(TAG, "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");
```

My log contains the line above, but after waiting for a while I still didn't get anything. I tried closing and reopening the app, as well as reinstalling it, but nothing has worked as of now. Nothing else is indicated in the log.

Here is the app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Here is the manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="FacePhotoDemo"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="face"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".PhotoViewerActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_photo_viewer"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is the PhotoViewerActivity which is where the isOperational() method is used:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.patch.SafeFaceDetector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;

import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Demonstrates basic usage of the GMS vision face detector by running face landmark detection on a
 * photo and displaying the photo with associated landmarks in the UI.
 */
public class PhotoViewerActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "PhotoViewerActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_viewer);

        InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.face);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

        // A new face detector is created for detecting the face and its landmarks.
        //
        // Setting "tracking enabled" to false is recommended for detection with unrelated
        // individual images (as opposed to video or a series of consecutively captured still
        // images).  For detection on unrelated individual images, this will give a more accurate
        // result.  For detection on consecutive images (e.g., live video), tracking gives a more
        // accurate (and faster) result.
        //
        // By default, landmark detection is not enabled since it increases detection time.  We
        // enable it here in order to visualize detected landmarks.
        FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTrackingEnabled(false)
                .setLandmarkType(FaceDetector.ALL_LANDMARKS)
                .build();

        // This is a temporary workaround for a bug in the face detector with respect to operating
        // on very small images.  This will be fixed in a future release.  But in the near term, use
        // of the SafeFaceDetector class will patch the issue.
        Detector<Face> safeDetector = new SafeFaceDetector(detector);

        // Create a frame from the bitmap and run face detection on the frame.
        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
        SparseArray<Face> faces = safeDetector.detect(frame);

        if (!safeDetector.isOperational()) {
            // Note: The first time that an app using face API is installed on a device, GMS will
            // download a native library to the device in order to do detection.  Usually this
            // completes before the app is run for the first time.  But if that download has not yet
            // completed, then the above call will not detect any faces.
            //
            // isOperational() can be used to check if the required native library is currently
            // available.  The detector will automatically become operational once the library
            // download completes on device.
            Log.w(TAG, "Face detector dependencies are not yet available.");

            // Check for low storage.  If there is low storage, the native library will not be
            // downloaded, so detection will not become operational.
            IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
            boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;

            if (hasLowStorage) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.low_storage_error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.low_storage_error));
            }
        }

        FaceView overlay = (FaceView) findViewById(R.id.faceView);
        overlay.setContent(bitmap, faces);

        // Although detector may be used multiple times for different images, it should be released
        // when it is no longer needed in order to free native resources.
        safeDetector.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having this exact issue. Did you get it resolved?

Comment: Sorry, I could solve it. It seems like this is a fairly rare problem that occurs only on some Android devices. I tried with 3 other phones and the exact same code actually worked. The phone on which this problem occurred was an LG Leon with Android 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and these are the steps I took to solve it

1. Ensure there's up to 500MB of storage on the device or emulator.
2. Update Google Play Services to latest version. Face detection was disabled for a while due to some bugs that were found but was reenabled in version 9.2.
3. Ensure your internet connection works. There's no way to check the progress of the download of the native libraries required but it should be done after a few minutes.

Hope this saves somebody a few hours.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but seems still relevant from my own experience. I have encountered two important additional issues while working with this tracker:

- if the image data is not rotated correctly, the face detector will
  not complain, but will just not detect anything. there is some
  freedom in face orientation (tilt to the side), but a 90° rotation or
  similar is definitely too much
- if you are working with a custom ROM, your phone might not be
  certified for Play store usage - you can get a certificate here:
  https://www.google.com/android/uncertified/ (but you need to figure
  out your Device ID first, there is an app with exactly this name for 
  it)